# PhpStorm: Won't receive changes of git submodule due to missing git remote

Tags: git, phpstorm, git-submodules

I have three projects (`Main`, `Submodule`, `Test`).

I added the `Submodule` project as `git submodule` in `Main` (which contains a lot of other code) and in `Test` (which is empty).

Afterwards, I make changes in the `Submodule` project, commit and push them.

[image]

When I press the <kbd>Update Project</kbd>-Button in my IDE (PhpStorm) inside the `Test` project, it fetches all incoming changes of the project as well as the changes made to the `Submodule` project.

But when I press the <kbd>Update Project</kbd>-Button inside the `Main` project, it just fetches the incoming changes to the project but won't get the changes made to the `Submodule` project.

`git status` also says that there are changes when used in the `Test` project but says "up to date" when used in the `Submodule` project

Terminal on `Test` project:

```
PS C:\Users\USERNAME\PhpstormProjects\Test> git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   aar-shared (new commits)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
PS C:\Users\USERNAME\PhpstormProjects\Test>
```

Terminal on `Main` project:

```
PS C:\Users\USERNAME\PhpstormProjects\Main> git status
On branch add-shared-repo                               
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/add-shared-repo'.
                                                           
nothing to commit, working tree clean                      
PS C:\Users\USERNAME\PhpstormProjects\Main>
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? How can I bring the submodule up to date?

**UPDATE:**

I just found a difference between my two projects `Main` and `Test`.

In the `Test` project the "Manage Remotes"-Window looks like this:

[image]

In the `Main` project it looks like this:

[image]

I don't know why it wasn't added automatically like in the `Test` project but to all the PhpStorm people out there, does anyone know how to add those grouping to the remotes, so like in the first picture "just-a-test" and "aar-shared" above the corresponding remotes?

When I try to add a new remote manually I can just add the name (like origin) and URL.

Comment: I think you miss something with submodules. You have to commit into the submodule the submodule changes then you need to commit into the repository the submodule. If you don't tell to main to use a differente submodule version, all is good for main. You need to update the submodule inside main then commit main

Comment: Is your (or does your question include) "what the heck is PHPStorm doing, in Git terms, when I press this button?" (If so you need to ask the php-storm people, not the Git people.)

Comment: Thanks for your both answers, but as mentioned above: It's working fine and as expected inside the Test-Project, and while doing the exact same stuff inside the Main-Project it behaves differently and won't get the changes of the submodule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE 2: Solved**

Just found it:

In `Settings > Version Control > Directory Mappings` I needed to add a new entry and select the submodule folder inside the project and set "VCS" to "Git".

Now it's working as expected just like in the `Test` project.